# Use a different form based on variable

Tags: django

I have a "product" field that I want to use to determine which form to display.  I am trying to do this in the view but wondering if I should do it in the template instead.  I have tried the following but "form" does not get assigned by my if statements. What am I doing wrong?

```
@login_required
def update_message(request, pk):
    message = get_object_or_404(Submission, pk=pk)
    author = message.author
    date_posted = message.date_posted
    product = message.product
    message_obj = Submission.objects.get(pk=pk)
    program_type = message.program_type

if author == request.user:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if product == 'Apple':
            form = AppleForm(request.user, request.POST, instance=message)

        if product == 'Orange':
            form = OrangeForm(request.user, request.POST, instance=message)


        if form.is_valid():
            message_sub = form.save(commit=False)
            message_sub.author = request.user
            message_sub.date_posted = timezone.now()
            message_sub.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            messages.success(request, 'Message updated')
            return redirect('submission-list')
    else:
        if product == 'Apple':
            form = AppleForm(request.user, instance=message)

        if product == 'Orange':
            form = OrangeForm(request.user, instance=message)

else:
    messages.warning(request, 'You can't do that.')
    return redirect('message-submission-list')

return render(request, 'programs/submission_create_form.html', {'product':product,'form': form, 'message_obj': message_obj,'program_type':program_type})
```

class MessageSubmission(models.Model):

```
message = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
program_code = models.ManyToManyField(Program)
program_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
production_cycle = models.ManyToManyField('ProductionCycle', null=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):

    return reverse('submission-list')

def __str__(self):

    return self.message
```

Comment: If the form variable is not assigned, then neither of your `if` statements are true. What is `message.product`? Show the Submission model definition.

Comment: I passed "product" to the template as a test, it passes either Apple or Orange just fine and displays it. Thats why I don't understand why the ifs aren't working.

Comment: Fine but what *is* that field? For example if it's a foreign key to another model, it might print as "Apple" but not be directly equal to "Apple". Show the definition.

Comment: Yes I think you might be on to something, it is a FK. I just updated the post with the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the issue is that `product` is a ForeignKey to another model. In the template, the FK will display using the `__str__` method of that model, but that doesn't make it *equal* to that display value. You should compare explicitly with the relevant field on the target model:

```
if product.fruit_type == 'Orange'   # or whatever the field is
```

(Alternatively you could do `if str(product) == 'Orange'` but that's more brittle and is coupling display logic in a way that's not very nice.)

Comment: Awesome, I see that now. I set it to message.product.name == 'Orange' and it works fine.  I also tried the str and that worked too, but ill definitely use the first method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing this in the views. If the form is not defined after those `if` statements then it means that the value of `product` is not `Apple` or `Orange`, but something else. I would double check the value of `product` to fix the issue.

---

Since `Product` is a class, you should reference a field. You didn't post the code for it, but for example

```
if form == product.name
```

If there is a `name` field.